# Generate html table for a named tuple or raw_dict

Tags: python, html, redis

I am trying to generate html table for a named tuple or a raw_dict, can someone provide an example of how I cando with my below named tuple or raw_dict, I would prefer to print named tuple.

```
import redis
import json

from collections import namedtuple

YbFlowRawMessage = namedtuple('YbFlowRawMessage', 'yid created_ts log_level sye type source message ip_address')


HOST = "abc"

r = redis.StrictRedis(HOST)

days = sorted(r.smembers('ybflow:days-logged'),reverse=True)

recent = days[0]

template = """

<table>
    <tr></tr>
    {row}
</table>

"""
```

### the below messages variable is a raw_dict

```
messages = [ json.loads(r.lindex(recent,k)) for k in range(r.llen(recent)) ]
```

## I am converting to named tuple

```
def convert_to_ybflowrawmessage(raw_dict):
    return YbFlowRawMessage(
        raw_dict['yid'],
        raw_dict['created_ts'],
        raw_dict['log_level'],
        raw_dict['sye'],
        raw_dict['type'],
        raw_dict['source'],
        raw_dict['message'],
        raw_dict['ip_address']
    )
```

## I would like to print ybflow_messages as a html table.

```
ybflow_messages = [ convert_to_ybflowrawmessage(x) for x in messages ]
```

when I print ybflow_messages directly in python interpreter, this is how it looks.

In [60]: print (r.ybflow_messages)

[YbFlowRawMessage(yid=None, created_ts=1332288190, log_level=u'info', sye=None, type=u'YbFlowRawMessage', source=u'oracle-rep1-new-yearbooks', message=u'sending 7 new yearbooks for processing', ip_address=u'172.20.100.41'), YbFlowRawMessage(yid=u'152356', created_ts=1332288280, log_level=u'info', sye=u'3300:1976:0', type=u'YbFlowRawMessage', source=u'YBMV', message=u'Successfully moved the yearbook to archive location!', ip_address=u'172.20.200.154'), YbFlowRawMessage(yid=u'152357', created_ts=1332288576, log_level=u'info', sye=u'176:1978:0', type=u'YbFlowRawMessage', source=u'YBMV', message=u'Successfully moved the yearbook to archive location!', ip_address=u'172.20.200.154'),